# mongo is not connecting but installed and show version

Tags: mongodb

i have following step.

```
              sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
              sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
              deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen
              sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen
```

when i run command 
                 mongo --version 
result was
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
then at command

```
            sudo start mongodb
```

result 
mongodb start/running, process 5808
at command
               sudo stop mongodb

result was 
stop: Unknown instance:
at command

```
           mongo
```

result was .MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
Sun Mar  2 18:57:50.050 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed
again on command

```
           sudo service mongodb restart
```

stop: Unknown instance: 
mongodb start/running, process 5873

```
           mongo
```

MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
Sun Mar  2 18:57:50.050 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to remove .lock file from /var/lib/mongodb/ ?

`sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo service mongodb restart`

Also you can try: `sudo -u mongodb mongod --repair --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/` and then start mongo again.

Hope this helps

Comment: i tried the two option  the result is still                  'MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
Sun Mar  2 19:43:05.534 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed